# R error - "No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8. Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text."

Tags: r, api

I wrote this code (below) to access census data from the "tidycensus" package and everything worked fine for about 7 days. There were no changes to the code and for some reason, one day the code just stopped working. the error that I was getting was:

> No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
>   Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
>      `<html>     <head>         <titl`
>                       (right here) ------^

I am running the newest version of R and Rstudio (as of 9/12/2018 these are R 3.5.1 and R studio 1.1.456) on a Mac Book Air - Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. Keep in mind I removed the API key, so to test out the code you will need to get one here: https://api.census.gov/data/key_signup.html.

```
# load the required packages
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(sp)
library(spatialEco)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(tigris)
library(readr)
library(reshape)

### PART 1: retrieve the Census API data ###
# load the packman package (package management)
if(!require(pacman)){install.packages("pacman");
  library(pacman)}

# load the required pacakges
p_load(ggplot2, tidycensus, dplyr)

#input the API Key
#acs_key <- census_api_key("INSERT CENSUS KEY HERE", install = TRUE)
acs_key <- Sys.getenv("INSERT CENSUS KEY HERE")

# search for variables
# The function takes two required arguments: 
# the year of the Census or endyear of the ACS sample, and the dataset - one of "sf1", "sf3", or "acs5"
v15 <- load_variables(2016, "acs5", cache = TRUE)

# store the variable names to a vector 
# vul_vars <- c("B01003_001E","B02001_002E","B02001_003E","B02001_004E","B02001_005E","B02001_006E","B02001_007E","B02001_008E","B03002_012E","B01001_002E",
#              "B01001_026E","B01002_001E","B01002_002E","B01002_003E","B20002_001E","B20002_002E","B20002_003E","B08135_001E","B08006_001E","B08006_002E",
#              "B08006_003E","B08006_004E","B08006_008E","B08006_014E","B08006_015E","B08006_016E","B08006_018E","B08006_019E","B08006_020E","B08006_021E",
#              "B08006_025E","B08006_031E","B08006_032E","B08006_033E","B08006_035E","B08006_036E","B08006_037E","B08006_038E","B08006_042E","B08006_048E",
#              "B08006_049E","B08006_050E","B08121_001E","B08121_002E","B08121_003E","B08121_004E","B08121_005E","B08121_006E","B09008_002E","B09008_004E",
#              "B09008_005E","B09010_002E","B09010_003E","B09010_004E","B09010_005E","B09010_006E","B09010_007E","B09019_002E","B09019_003E","B09019_005E",
#              "B09019_006E","B09019_007E","B09019_008E","B09019_024E","B09019_038E","B15003_002E","B15003_016E","B15003_017E","B15003_018E","B15003_020E",
#              "B15003_022E","B15003_023E","B15003_025E","B16001_002E","B16001_002E","B16001_002E","B23025_004E","B23025_005E","B17020_002E","B08201_002E",
#              "B08201_002E","B19013_001E","B19013A_001E","B19013B_001E")

vul_vars <- c("B01003_001","B02001_002","B02001_003","B02001_004","B02001_005","B02001_006","B02001_007","B02001_008","B03002_012","B01001_002",
             "B01001_026","B01002_001","B01002_002","B01002_003","B20002_001","B20002_002","B20002_003","B08135_001","B08006_001","B08006_002",
             "B08006_003","B08006_004","B08006_008","B08006_014","B08006_015","B08006_016","B08006_018","B08006_019","B08006_020","B08006_021",
             "B08006_025","B08006_031","B08006_032","B08006_033","B08006_035","B08006_036","B08006_037","B08006_038","B08006_042","B08006_048",
             "B08006_049","B08006_050","B08121_001","B08121_002","B08121_003","B08121_004","B08121_005","B08121_006","B09008_002","B09008_004",
             "B09008_005","B09010_002","B09010_003","B09010_004","B09010_005","B09010_006","B09010_007","B09019_002","B09019_003","B09019_005",
             "B09019_006","B09019_007","B09019_008","B09019_024","B09019_038","B15003_002","B15003_016","B15003_017","B15003_018","B15003_020",
             "B15003_022","B15003_023","B15003_025","B16001_002","B16001_002","B16001_002","B23025_004","B23025_005","B17020_002","B08201_002",
             "B08201_002","B19013_001","B19013A_001","B19013B_001")

vul_vars <- unique(vul_vars)
# grab the data for all of the states
vul_acs <-
  get_acs(geography = "tract", variables = vul_vars,
          state = c("NY","IL","DC"), output = "wide")
```

Comment: Couple things: I'm on a similar setup and use `tidycensus` almost every day for work. Your code is working for me right now with my API key. But the Bureau has been changing stuff with the API that folks are keeping up with on the `tidycensus` [issues](https://github.com/walkerke/tidycensus/issues). The API also crashes pretty often. For debugging, I'd recommend a much smaller API call--fewer variables, fewer states.

Comment: Thanks - so I've had a number of people run my code and they said it has been fine for them. What do you think is the issue? (either R or R studio or related to my computer?)

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session? (Sounds silly but sometimes that's all the problem is)

Comment: Yes, I did, I even uninstalled R and Rstudio, but no luck. It seems odd that it would just stop working all of a sudden.

Answer (score 0):

So I just had a similar problem to yours and found out that I had copied and pasted a period to the end of my api key that was causing it to generate the same errors. Although its a guess based off my recent experience getting the same error, try checking if there's an accidental period at the end of your api key and remove it. If that is what's causing the error, the rest should work just fine as I also just tested your code too and it worked fine for me